# Multiply answer is wrong and i don't get it

Tags: python

So my problem is Im supposed to make a program that asks a number from the user and if it's smaller than 0 it multiplies the given number by -1 and prints, if bigger it just prints the number the user gave. The idea is to tell the user the absolute value. Problem is the "number" is always wrong, for example -7 * -1 should show 7 and I Don't get what is going wrong here. Yes, Im new and been trying to learn for a couple hours now.

```
number = int(input("Give a number: "))
if number <  0:
    print (number * -1)
print()
print ("The absolute value of the number is: " + str (number))
```

I've tried for an hour and just don't get what is wrong here

Comment: What is the current behaviour of your application? Like what comes out for inputs: -5, 0, 5?

Comment: In the event the number is less than 0 did you want to print it or did you want to reasign it? `number = number * -1`?

Comment: It seems like you are printing "number" as given from the user every time no matter what. I think you only want to print "number" as is if your if statement on line 2 is false. To do this, you can use an "else" statement.

Comment: If number is less than 0, you're printing the product `number * -1`, but that doesn't actually CHANGE the value of number.  It's STILL negative.

Comment: "Problem is the "number" is always wrong" - in your own words: in the code that you have written so far, what parts of it do you believe can cause the `number` to *change*? Why and how do they do so? Where the code says `print ("The absolute value of the number is: " + str (number))`, do I understand correctly, that your intent is for `number` to have been made positive *by that point*? Step by step, how do you expect the code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is your operation is not performed "inplace" - you first seem to multiply with `-1` but don't store the result. You need to store the result

```py
number = int(input("Give a number: ")) 

if number < 0: 
    number = number * -1  # Here we re-assign number to -number

print("The absolute value of the number is:", number)
```

A simpler apporach is to use the builtin `abs()` function

```py
number = int(input("Give a number: ")) 
print(abs(number))
```

Comment: You don't need to print in both branches of the if/else (do it after). Also, `print("...", number)` - print knows how to print integers.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: I would also use `number = -number` or `number *= -1`, but that's perhaps not what the syllabus says ;-)

Comment: I mostly wanted to keep the original code intact, but sure, it's probably better to be idiomatic to set a better example? Which was also why I shows the built-in `abs()` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯